# Not able to register/unregister DLL files using Regasm

Tags: .net, dll, .net-4.5, regasm

I'm encountering ongoing issues with trying to register .NET DLL's for use within Excel. This is on the test server where we've had to uninstall and install new releases very frequently. Of late, attempting to register or unregister is failing to work (even though it confirms it is being unregistered, it still is picked up etc.). Could this be the register being corrupted? The command I'm using is:

```
%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\Background Worker\DExcelUtils.dll" /unregister
%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\Background Worker\DExcelUtils.dll" /register /tlb:"DExcelUtils.tlb" /codebase
```

Comment: This cannot work of course.  You have to unregister the *old* version of the assembly, *before* it is rebuilt.  As posted, using /unregister is pointless.  The registry of the machine is probably heavily polluted.

Comment: If the file name and location are the same, then why would it matter? Also - what is the best way to clean up the registry from all the mess?